# Find the square of a number using recursion with one parameter function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Below is a (trivial) C++ function which returns the square of its parameter (a non-negative integer):

```
unsigned int square(unsigned int n) {
    return n*n;
}
```

Your job:  write a function which also returns n<sup>2</sup> but with the following constraints:

- You cannot use the multiplication operator `*`
- You cannot use the division operator `/`
- You cannot have any loops
- You cannot add any additional parameters to the function
- Your function must be self-contained:  no helper functions!
- You cannot use any globals
- You cannot use any static variables
- You cannot use any "bit twiddling" operations -- no shifts, etc.

However, …

- You can use recursion
- You can use the `+` and `-` operators.

So far I have tried getting the square using the n(n+n+n+...), but for that I need something that keeps track of the recursive cycle, but because the function can only have one parameter I need another way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Hint: `n^2 == (n-1)^2 + n + n - 1`

Comment: Show your code that fails.

Comment: This is an interesting question but it is also clearly somewhat of a homework dump (which is why it is getting downvoted a lot). While you explained your work so far, the exercise and its solution are of little practical use to others (unless they have to solve the exact same homework), so it is not really a good question for stackoverflow.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't see how adding code that obviously violates one of the constraints helps improve the question. It's not like there is a lot of footwork for the real answer, it's literally a one-liner, so iterating existing code towards it is not going to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to implement the square operation as a recursive function, you need first to express the operation in terms of itself:

*(n-1)<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup> - 2n + 1* `-->` *n<sup>2</sup> = (n-1)<sup>2</sup> + 2n - 1*

Then, in order to avoid the operator `*`:

*2n = n + n*

Therefore, *n<sup>2</sup> = (n-1)<sup>2</sup> + n + n - 1*

---

With that in mind, you can easily implement `square()` as a *recursive function* that does not use the operator `*`:

```
unsigned int square(unsigned int n) {
   if (n == 0)
      return 0; // base case

   return square(n-1) + n + n - 1; // recursive case
}
```

Or just with a single statement using the *ternary operator*:

```
unsigned int square(unsigned int n) {
   return n? square(n-1) + n + n - 1: 0;
}
```

`n` equal to zero is the *base case* (i.e., when the recursion stops). It returns zero for this case, since 0<sup>2</sup> is zero.